# What does figure(1) do?

Tags: matplotlib

I am currently trying to understand why `figure(1)` influences the following code. Although the value isn't stored anywhere and it's not applied to an object which gets used later, I can't simply remove it. So it has to change the state somehow.

What does `figure(1)` do in the following code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Source: http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/fnn.html
from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet
from pybrain.utilities import percentError
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure.modules import SoftmaxLayer

# Only needed for data generation and graphical output
from pylab import ion, ioff, figure, draw, contourf, clf, show, hold, plot
from scipy import diag, arange, meshgrid, where
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal

INPUT_FEATURES = 2
CLASSES = 3
HIDDEN_NODES = 5

means = [(-1, 0), (2, 4), (3, 1)]
cov = [diag([1, 1]), diag([0.5, 1.2]), diag([1.5, 0.7])]
alldata = ClassificationDataSet(INPUT_FEATURES, 1, nb_classes=CLASSES)
for n in range(400):
    for klass in range(CLASSES):
        features = multivariate_normal(means[klass], cov[klass])
        alldata.addSample(features, [klass])

tstdata, trndata = alldata.splitWithProportion(0.25)

trndata._convertToOneOfMany()
tstdata._convertToOneOfMany()

print("Number of training patterns: %i" % len(trndata))
print("Input and output dimensions: %i, %i" % (trndata.indim, trndata.outdim))
print("First sample (input, target, class):")
print(trndata['input'][0], trndata['target'][0], trndata['class'][0])

fnn = buildNetwork(trndata.indim, HIDDEN_NODES, trndata.outdim,
                   outclass=SoftmaxLayer)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(fnn, dataset=trndata, momentum=0.1,
                          verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01)

ticks = arange(-3., 6., 0.2)
X, Y = meshgrid(ticks, ticks)
# need column vectors in dataset, not arrays
griddata = ClassificationDataSet(INPUT_FEATURES, 1, nb_classes=CLASSES)
for i in range(X.size):
    griddata.addSample([X.ravel()[i], Y.ravel()[i]], [0])

for i in range(20):
    trainer.trainEpochs(1)
    trnresult = percentError(trainer.testOnClassData(),
                             trndata['class'])
    tstresult = percentError(trainer.testOnClassData(
                             dataset=tstdata), tstdata['class'])

    print("epoch: %4d" % trainer.totalepochs,
          "  train error: %5.2f%%" % trnresult,
          "  test error: %5.2f%%" % tstresult)
    out = fnn.activateOnDataset(griddata)
    out = out.argmax(axis=1)  # the highest output activation gives the class
    out = out.reshape(X.shape)

    figure(1)
    ioff()  # interactive graphics off
    clf()   # clear the plot
    #hold(True)  # overplot on
    for c in [0, 1, 2]:
        here, _ = where(tstdata['class'] == c)
        plot(tstdata['input'][here, 0], tstdata['input'][here, 1], 'o')
    if out.max() != out.min():  # safety check against flat field
        contourf(X, Y, out)   # plot the contour
    ion()   # interactive graphics on
    draw()  # update the plot

ioff()
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does indeed manipulate some internal state. You can look at the source file to see it is calling a method on a "private" attribute of the class it's contained in:

```
_pylab_helpers.Gcf.set_active(figManager)
```

The source code also documents this function:

> ```
> Create a new figure.
>
> call signature::
>
>   figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
>
> Create a new figure and return a :class:`matplotlib.figure.Figure`
> instance.  If *num* = *None*, the figure number will be incremented and
> a new figure will be created.  The returned figure objects have a
> *number* attribute holding this number.
>
> If *num* is an integer, and ``figure(num)`` already exists, make it
> active and return a reference to it.  If ``figure(num)`` does not exist
> it will be created.  Numbering starts at 1, MATLAB style::
>
>   figure(1)
> ```

When you call `figure(2)`, a new figure is created and activated. Later if you call `figure(1)` (which already exists), that figure becomes active instead. And yes it is the canvas - as you can see, you are setting the size, dpi, color etc.

Comment: But what is `figure(1)` needed for? What happens when I make `figure(2)`? Is figure the canvas that is drawn on?

Comment: When you call `figure(2)`, a new figure is created and activated. Later if you call `figure(1)` (which already exists), that figure becomes active instead. And yes it is the canvas - as you can see, you are setting the size, dpi, color etc.

Comment: Could you please add that comment to your answer? That was what I  was looking for.